# Wordpress loading all local images from specific directory?

Tags: php, images, uploads

I need to load some local images..
I used this code before to load some images

```
        <?php 
        function loopImages(){
            $imagePath = get_stylesheet_directory()."/IMAGES/sponsors/";
            $filesList =glob($imagePath.'*.{JPG,jpg,PNG,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
            echo $filesList;
            foreach($filesList as $file){
                echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
            }
        }
        loopImages();
    ?>
```

This worked almost fine. I could loop through files and browser could render 8 img tags, but it showed it cannot load local images so I changed `get_stylesheet_directory()` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` like this

```
         function loopImages(){
            $imagePath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/IMAGES/sponsors/";
            $filesList =glob($imagePath.'*.{JPG,jpg,PNG,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
            echo $filesList;
            foreach($filesList as $file){
                echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
            }
        }
        loopImages();
```

but, it shows nothing. Just nothing. What did I do wrong? How can I render my local images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_directory` was necessary for the `glob` function to work, you need a combination of both, e.g. fetch the files in that directory:

```php
$imagePath = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/IMAGES/sponsors/";
$filesList = glob( $imagePath . '*.{JPG,jpg,PNG,png}', GLOB_BRACE );
```

and display the files at that URL:

```php
$imagePathURL = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/IMAGES/sponsors/";
...
    echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $imagePathURL . basename( $file ) ) . '">';
```

Notice that I wrapped it in `esc_url`, this is escaping and we do it to keep things secure and avoid injection attacks.

TLDR:

- `glob` wants a folder path
- but `<img` wants a URL instead

Comment: Thank you for answer, I did esc_url as you said but the url of the image is really strange. after sponsors/, comes C:Users blah blah.. and of course I get 404 error..

Comment: ok, solved it by using basename($file) in esc_url. Thank you for help